# No Video Playback in Web (Epiphany), Videos (Totem)and Gthumb

Tags: gnome, video, video-player

Running 17.10 (gnome session and xorg).
I seem to have lost the ability to playback videos in Web(Epiphany), Videos(Totem) and Gthumb. Other applications such as VLC and Gnome MPV still work fine, as does Firefox. Have I accidentally disrupted a dependency or something?
Any help would be very welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a little more detail i was geting audio but no image just a green screen in all the named apps.
This solved it: `sudo apt purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi`

Comment: I have a very similar issue on 18.04, for which I created https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer-vaapi/+bug/1784242 . I suppose it comes from a bad VAAPI support on some specific CPUs (Core i5 M 540 in my case). I use the same workaround

Comment: similar for me with a i7 3770. After applying this workaround, the video plays, but in a separate window - anyone know of a fix to that?